# Apache2 ProxyPass to an NGinx API on different Port

Tags: codeigniter, mod-rewrite, nginx, apache2, mod-proxy

Apache2 has a codeigniter app running. It requires an API call to be made which is running a Sinatra app on a different port and is behing NGinx.

Apache2 is running on port 80
Nginx is running on port 81.

For a few URLs of type /auth/(.*)$ , we should redirect the apache request to http://localhost:81/auth/$1 .

I tried both ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse and also, RewriteRule but we always end up redirecting or sending the post request to /login which is default when we hit "/"

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/auth.*$
  RewriteRule ^/auth/(.*)$ http://localhost:81/auth/$1
```

and using ProxyPass

```
DocumentRoot       /srv/app/www
DirectoryIndex     index.php

ProxyPass ^/auth/(.*)$ http://localhost:81/auth/$1
ProxyPassReverse ^/auth/(.*)$ http://localhost:81/auth/$1
```

I tried even Redirect and RedirectPermanent.

Ideally any request on port 80 to /auth should hit the nginx authentication service on port 81 localhost:81/auth/... and then, return the results.